# How to choose a color type for the photo to be displayed with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if I could change the `[cmap="gray"]` thing to other colors such as "cmap=yellow or blue", but it didn't work that way. I thought there are some color types that are already set in the library because I didn't define the color gray. But when I put `cmap="gray"`, it printed the picture in gray color. Can someone explain this for me? Thank you for your help in advance ^^

------below is the code I'm working on-----[*It's in "line 3" which I'm asking about*]

```
#[line 1] 
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#[line 2] 
image = cv2.imread("images/cybertruck.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

#[line 3]
plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib has a nice overview of [existing colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html). For a black&white image, any ["sequential colormap"](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#sequential) would do. Note that some have the dark and light reversed. Appending "_r" at the end of the name would reverse them. For example, to see the image in negative, choose `cmap="gray_r"`.

Note that the quotes (either double or single) are needed if you want to use them in `cmap="gray"`. Scroll down the docs page to see how they look like, or experiment with your own image.

Some code to generate many examples:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import ceil

cmap_list1 = ['viridis', 'plasma', 'inferno', 'magma', 'cividis']
cmap_list2 = ['Greys', 'Purples', 'Blues', 'Greens', 'Oranges', 'Reds',
              'YlOrBr', 'YlOrRd', 'OrRd', 'PuRd', 'RdPu', 'BuPu',
              'GnBu', 'PuBu', 'YlGnBu', 'PuBuGn', 'BuGn', 'YlGn']
cmap_list3 = ['binary', 'gist_yarg', 'gist_gray', 'gray', 'bone', 'pink',
              'spring', 'summer', 'autumn', 'winter', 'cool', 'Wistia',
              'hot', 'afmhot', 'gist_heat', 'copper']
cmap_list4 = ['ocean', 'gist_earth', 'terrain', 'gist_stern',
              'gnuplot', 'gnuplot2', 'CMRmap', 'cubehelix', 'brg',
              'gist_rainbow', 'rainbow', 'jet', 'nipy_spectral', 'gist_ncar']
image = cv2.imread("test_image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# cmap_list = cmap_list1 + cmap_list2
cmap_list = cmap_list3 + cmap_list4
try_reversed_map = False
ncols = 7
nrows = int(ceil(len(cmap_list) / ncols))
if nrows <= 1: nrows = 2  # subplots returns single list instead of matrix when nrows=1
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=ncols, nrows=nrows, figsize=(14, 4 * nrows))

for i in range(nrows):
    for j in range(ncols):
        ax = axs[i, j]
        ax.axis("off")
        if i * ncols + j < len(cmap_list):
            cmap = cmap_list[i * ncols + j]
            if try_reversed_map:
                cmap += "_r"
            ax.imshow(image, cmap=cmap)
            ax.set_title(cmap)
plt.show()
```

[image: example images]